# Why do directional microphones have a high bass response at short distances?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, electronics, electrical-engineering

In the audio field, it is taken as a given that directional microphones have a higher response at lower frequencies when the source is close to the microphone.  Many directional microphones have a switchable high-pass filter to compensate for this.

What is the underlying cause of this?

Comment: Approximate distances (how close is close?) and a description or diagram of the apparatus (especially any hollow or mostly-hollow structures open on one end, and the position of the actual vibrating part of the microphone sensor) would be helpful.

Comment: Also: how low is lower frequency? I suspect that you are noticing this effect when the distance between the sensor and the source is much less than one wavelength (approximately divide 340m/s by frequency) e.g. much less than 3.4m for 100Hz sound, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Introduction

The phenomenon you describe is termed ***"The Proximity Effect"***. Indeed, the effect is exhibited only by directional microphones. This connection is due to the fact that directional microphones' voltage output results from the pressure gradient (this is why they are sometimes called either pressure gradient microphones or - mistakenly in my opinion - velocity microphones) acting on the diaphragm.

### Pressure Gradient Microphones

As already stated, directional microphones' directional response results from the pressure gradient acting on the diaphragm (difference of the pressure acting on the front and back side). The simplest pressure gradient microphone is that with a polar pattern termed *"Figure-of-Eight"* shown in the picture below

[image]

In this case, the diaphragm is exposed to sound from both sides. If the angle of incidence is $\theta = \pm 90^{o}$ the sound pressure $p$ is identical on both sides of the diaphragm and the pressure gradient (differential) $\Delta p$ is $0$, resulting in zero voltage output, $V = 0$. For arbitrary angles of incidence $\Delta p \neq 0$ so $V \neq 0$ too.

In addition to the pressure difference there is an angle-dependent delay, resulting in some phase difference $\Delta \phi \neq 0$ for all angles except for the $\theta = \pm 90^{0}$ cases. Nevertheless, due to the small dimensions of the diaphragm this phase difference results in negligible amplitude differences for low frequencies and does not contribute much (even if it does have some contribution is so small that, when taking into account psychoacoustic effects it is not noticeable).

The same principle applies to all directional microphones but the resulting delay is different for the different polar patterns and there's always some manufacturing variations.

### Source Radiation

This section describes the "rough approximations" of sound source radiation characteristics (it is indeed debatable how much those approximations resemble real-life sound sources' radiation characteristics and to what degree). It will become apparent why understanding the radiation behavior of the sources helps describe the proximity effect.

The two most prominent sound sources used in acoustics are the infinite (or at least very large) planes resulting in plane waves where there is zero, or negligible, geometrical attenuation and the point source (or radially vibrating sphere) resulting in spherical waves. The latter exhibit geometrical attenuation because the emitted energy is spread out in larger spheres with increasing distance. The "inverse square law" describes this attenuation for such sources as $p \sim \frac{1}{r}$, with $r$ denoting the distance from the source. Thus, pressure is halved for each distance doubling, resulting in $\sim 6 ~ dB_{SPL}$ drop. A well-known picture of the formulation is shown below

[image]

Assuming all sources are point sources, at an adequate (see below) distance from the source, the wave-front curvature becomes extremely low and, at least locally, the wave resembles a plane wave. Apart from some rules-of-thumb used a lot in acoustics to estimate the distance for which this happens, the most formal definition of the transition from the spherical to plane wave (sometimes associated with the far-field) is the "coherency" of the pressure and the particle velocity. This is, how much the two quantities are in-phase (the angle of their vectors becomes smaller). The equations for sound pressure and particle velocity for the point source are

$$ p \left( r \right) = \frac{j \omega \rho Q}{4 \pi r} e^{j \left(\omega t - k r \right)} \tag{1} \label{1} $$
$$ u \left( r \right) = \frac{j k Q}{4 \pi r} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{j k r} \right) e^{j \left(\omega t - k r \right)} = \frac{p \left( r \right)}{\rho c} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{j k r} \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

with $p$ the pressure, $u$ the particle velocity, $r$ being the distance from the source, $\omega$ the radial frequency for which $\omega = 2 \pi f$ is true with $f$ denoting the frequency, $\rho$ the medium (air mostly) density, $Q$ the "strength" of the source (actually is the volume velocity of the radially vibrating sphere), $k$ the wavenumber for which $k = \frac{\omega}{c} = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ is true, with $c$ being the speed of sound and $\lambda$ the wavelength (distance travelled in the duration of one period $T = \frac{1}{f}$). Finally note that $j$ is the imaginary unit, also found as $i$ for which $j^{2} = -1$ (thanks to Robert Bristow-Johnson for the hint).

As can be seen from equations \ref{1} and \ref{2}, the further away you go from the source, the more in-phase the pressure and particle velocity are. The phase relation between pressure and particle velocity is apparent in equation \ref{2} where the second term in the parentheses adds an additional phase component due to its $\frac{1}{j}$ value (which can be expressed as $e^{-j \frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{1}{j}$). Nevertheless, this second term gets smaller and smaller with both increasing distance from the source (due to $r^{-1}$) and increasing frequency (due to $k^{-1} = \frac{c}{\omega} \sim \frac{1}{2 \pi f} \sim \frac{1}{f}$). This behavior results in the pressure and particle velocity acquiring the same phase asymptotically for $r \rightarrow \infty$ where the second term in the parentheses will go to $0$. For practical reasons though, when the second term becomes negligible (you can define "negligibility" - I like the term :D - yourself by for example saying that you would like the phase difference to be less than a specified value that suites your case) we discard it altogether and treat the sound-field as consisting of plane waves.

As stated above, due to the $k^{-1}$ dependency of the particle velocity phase, the pressure to particle velocity difference is frequency dependent with higher frequencies reaching the "plane wave approximation" way faster than the low frequencies. This observation is important when we try to understand why the proximity effect applies only to low frequencies.

---

To answer another question posted in the comments, I'll try to provide some insight as to what does it mean to "reach the plane wave approximation". Before attempting to do so, let me state that for this task the "evanescent waves" approach described by Bulbasaur (see also the last part of this answer) may more appropriate from a mathematical viewpoint.

The main difference between plane and spherical waves relevant to our problem is the geometrical attenuation complying to the "inverse square law" $p \sim r^{-1}$. Taking some numerical examples, let's say for a distance of $r_{1} = 1 ~ m$ a change of $10 ~ cm$ with $r_{2} = r_{1} + 10 ~ cm = 1.1 ~ m$ would result in a change in amplitude of

$$ \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{r_{1}}}{\frac{1}{r_{2}}} \implies \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}} \implies \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{1.1}{1} \implies \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = 1.1 \implies p_{2} = \frac{p_{1}}{1.1} $$

for which $p_{2} < p_{1}$ with

$$ \frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}} = \frac{\frac{p_{1}}{1.1}}{p_{1}} = \frac{1}{1.1} \approx 0.91$$

Thus in this case, $p_{2}$ is about $10 \%$ less than $p_{1}$. Now, doing the same for a distance of $r_{1} = 10 ~ m$ and the same increase $r_{2} = r_{1} + 0.1 ~ m = 10 + 0.1 ~ m = 10.1 ~ m$ we get (omitting some of the calculations)

$$ \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}} \implies \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{10.1}{1} \implies p_{2} = \frac{p_{1}}{10.1} $$

where in this case $$ \frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}} = \frac{\frac{p_{1}}{10.1}}{p_{1}} = \frac{10}{10.1} \approx 0.99$$

so $p_{2} \approx 0.99 p_{1}$, or just $ 1 \%$ less. For the second case, we could easily say that we are approaching (or for some practical applications we are in) the far-field, which is a different way to say that we can treat the sound field as consisting of plane waves.

### The Proximity Effect

Finally, we will combine all the above to describe the ***"Proximity Effect"***.

First, we'll have a look at the phase difference between the two sides of the diaphragm. For the various polar plots, the delays and resulting phase shifts vary. No matter what, in the low frequencies, where the wavelengths are long, the phase difference will be small, resulting in small pressure gradients. This, somehow contradicts the fact that the bass response of many directional microphones is comparable to the highs. This is in fact something that microphone manufacturers take care of with some electronic bass boosting and possibly other "tricks" in the design. Since the phase shifts do not affect the bass boost experienced due to the proximity effect, we won't spend more time on it.

Now, there is also amplitude differences on each side of the diaphragm due to geometrical attenuation (as described above). Of course, the depth of the diaphragm is rather small, but there are cases where, for some polar patterns, the sound has to travel around the microphone capsule (and possibly part of the microphone's body) to go through a port on its back side and this further increases the effective distance travelled by the sound reaching the back side of the diaphragm.

For rather large distances from the source, the extra path travelled by the "back impinging" sound is very short compared to the distance from the source resulting in a really small attenuation due to the geometrical spreading. This shows that for distances larger than some value, increasing the distance from the source doesn't really affect the microphone response.  On the contrary, for very short distances, the length of the extra path travelled by the "back impinging" sound is comparable and can be equal or even longer than the distance from the source to the front of the diaphragm. Consulting the "inverse square law" stated above, we see that the "back impinging" sound can be attenuated by more than $6 ~ dB_{SPL}$ resulting in considerable pressure gradient values which will lead to increased voltage output. This, actually, is the main contribution to the ***"Proximity Effect"***!

Now, you may wonder why only low frequencies are affected. Consulting equations \ref{1} and \ref{2} you'll see that the high frequencies approach the "plane wave approximation" point very close to the source. Considering the fact that for plane waves the geometrical attenuation is non-existent (or very small), the pressure gradient resulting for those frequencies is not affected by the distance to the source (at least not as much as the low frequencies).

---

One could very well ask whether this geometrical attenuation applies to all frequencies in the same way. This is where equation \ref{2} comes into place. This equation contains (and "codes" if you'd like) the information needed to answer that question.

When the pressure and the particle velocity are not in phase, there is some energy that **does not** propagate outwards (is not radiated). This is similar (if not identical) to the energy consumption of electrical equipment when the voltage and current are not in phase. In this case, the inverse square law **does not** apply! In this case, the sound-field consists of the "in-phase" components (when particle velocity is seen as vector, the part that is in the same direction as the pressure gradient) and the "out-of-phase" components (these are the so called evanescent waves) that decay very rapidly with distance and do not contribute to the radiated energy. This is better described by the sound intensity where the active component propagates outwards and the reactive component does not (it kinda stores the energy locally and oscillates back and forth). For a better depiction see the next .gif.

[image]

Please note that this is not easily seen (if at all) for ideal point sources with $0$ dimensions but it very well applies to real-life sources. The transition of sound fields is the following. Very close to the source active and reactive intensity components coexist. Further away from the source, only the active intensity has propagated outwards and due to the high curvature of the waves they can be treated as spherical waves and even further away at distances that where the curvature is very small they are treated as (approximations of) plane waves.

Consulting the last image, one could visualise the situation where the wavelength would change. For longer wavelengths (lower frequencies) the interaction between particles would extend to larger areas (since the phase differences would cover greater distances) providing for a larger area (and outwards distance) where the neighboring particles would highly affect each other. On the contrary, shorter wavelengths would provide shorter lengths of interaction and higher cancellation of neighboring reactive areas which would force the evanescent waves to decay faster and thus reach the "area of active-only intensity components" in a shorter distance from the source.

Finally, to answer the last question in the comments (if the pressure gradient is the important factor wouldn't just equation \ref{1} be needed?). The answer is **yes**. This is the case for the two sound-fields containing only active intensity components and this is the equation used to calculate the **Proximity Effect** for simple applications (as a first approximation at least). Most often than not, the evanescent waves are omitted from consideration and their contribution is not taken into account since they decay very fast. In the our case, they work to enhance the phenomenon as they produce even higher pressure gradients due to their fast decay (with distance). Thus, equation \ref{2} serves as a good indication for both, the plane-wave approximation distance based on frequency (showing why high frequencies do not exhibit such pronounced proximity effect) and the fact that when very close to the source there will be higher complexity, most probably exaggerating even more the bass boost effect.

### Final Remarks

Please note that there are other phenomena also taking place here but are omitted since they do not contribute to the ***"Proximity Effect"*** as much as the geometrical attenuation factor.

One phenomenon taking place that may deserve mention is also stated in another answer by Bulbasaur. Close to the source, there are evanescent waves that do not radiate and are rapidly decayed with increasing distance from the source. This is reflected in the "out-of-phase" components of the pressure and particle velocity close to the source which, as already stated, decay with increasing distance and the two quantities "become coherent" (in-phase) further away from the source.

To the best of my knowledge, the evanescent waves approach is "a different side of the same coin". The evanescent waves are actually what creates the pressure gradient on the diaphragm due to their excess attenuation with distance, resulting in large pressure differences in the two sides of the microphone capsule. Furthermore, there is the tendency for evanescent waves to cancel in neighbouring areas when the frequency is adequately high (depends on the vibrating patterns of the source and the speed of "sound" in the source medium). This results in even faster attenuation with distance, allowing for the propagating/radiating components of the high frequencies to dominate even faster (closer to the source). Thus, the result is the same but described from a different viewpoint (using different mathematical formulations).

Comment: Since we're not in the Electrical Engineering or Signal Processing SE. you might wanna make it clear to these physikers that $j^2 = -1$.  They might be more used to "$i$".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @robertbristow-johnson. I am very used to using it in the "engineering way" that I didn't even think of explicitly stating the fact that it is the same as "$i$". I'll make sure to include it in the answer.

Comment: I have read the answer and I learned a lot but I still don't fully get it. If the pressure gradient is all that matters for the proximity effect, equation 1 should be able to explain everything right? So why mention equation 2? Also when you say "Consulting equations 1 and 2 you'll see that the high frequencies approach the "plane wave approximation" point very close to the source ...", I am puzzled, don't both the high frequency and low frequency sound waves' amplitdues decrease according to the 1/r law? So shouldn't the pressure gradient due to this geometric attenuation be same?

Comment: As your questions are quite broad to discuss in comments, I'll try to tackle them in the answer. Please let me know if they don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, I think now I get it much better. The confirmation "The answer is yes" and the paragraph starting with "When the pressure and the particle velocity are not in phase, there is some energy that does not propagate outwards" discussing the subtleties in near field are especially helpful for me.

Comment: Glad it was clarified, at least to some extent. I understand that it may not be entirely clear to you since there's quite some background that has to be covered before being able to completely grasp the effect. Most of it is some theoretical formulations of sources (as is apparent in the answer) which has to be noted that **are mere formulations** and their mathematical nature may be not trivial, especially when compared to real-life. I encourage you to post more questions that would attempt to cover all the gaps you may have in order to get a complete understanding.

Comment: Finally, I suggest you choose an answer as the correct answer if it satisfies you and do so for all the questions you post (if you get a satisfying answer of course), as this will help future users, as well as yourself, to easily find an answer to this question.

Comment: Dear ZaellixA, but I am not the guy who posted the initial question about directional microphones.

Comment: Oh... Hahahaha, I didn't notice that. I'm really sorry. At least I hope the answer did help you somehow :).

Comment: It indeed helps me a lot. Great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The frequency response function of a microphone does not depend on its position relative to a source. When a microphone is placed within the near-field of a source (something like $d<<wavelength/2$ where $d$ is the distance) the reactive intensity is usually high at this position since there is a ~90 degree phase difference of the pressure and velocity. In other words: In the near-field of an acoustic source fluid is moved back and forth without the pressure fluctuation propagating in the far field. Note that this effect is frequency-dependent. The reactive intensity components in the near field lead to high sound pressure recorded by the microphone. Since the effect is stronger at lower frequencies (due to the long wavelength) people try to compensate this using a high-pass filter.